# How to print barcode with epl using PrinterJob in java

Tags: java, barcode, zebra-printers

I have followed tutorial in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731265/4226651 and success print
the barcode but it print by default printer in computer setting, i want to choose the printer before print the barcode like using PrinterJob dialog, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread is of help and you can gain some ideas from it:

[How to use Java to print on a network printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230502/how-to-use-java-to-print-on-a-network-printer)

Comment: So do you want to choose the printer during runtime or do you want to specify it in your code?

Comment: i want to show dialog like PrinterJob did "job.printDialog()", but how to set the printable or pageable if have Doc (javax.print.doc) like in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/12731265/4226651 i'm sorry if miss to describe it